# Right logic increment to draw on JComponent (Java)

Tags: java, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to build a program that draws a function on a JFrame (using JComponent)... but I can't seem to get the right increment so that it correctly draws.

These variables are user-defined:

```
int lowerX // lower x domain
int higherX // higher x domain
int frameSizeX // horizontal frame size
int frameSizeY // vertical frame size
```

Suppose that I've successfully calculated f(x):

```
double valuesX[n] // x points from lower x domain to higher x domain
double valuesY[n] // y points from lower x domain to higher x domain
```

For example, if the lowerX = -4, higherX = 4, frameSizeX and frameSizeY = 1000, and the function was x^2:

```
valuesX[0] = -4, valuesX[1] = -3.992 | valuesY[0] = 16, valuesY[1] = 15.936064
```

I'm trying to build a valuesYGraph[] array that should do this:

```
(x = -4, y = 16) valuesYGraph[0] = 0,
(x = -3, y = 9) valuesYGraph[*] = 218.75 ... 
(x = 4, y = 16) valuesY[999] = 0.
```

* = whichever array is = -3

I'm been trying to solve this for the past few days, but I've been stuck. JComponent has the luxury of making +y go down rather than up, which makes it all the more confusing...

The increment should be universally valid too (as in, it would work for x^2 as well as sin(x) or x^5 + 5).

Any suggestions anyone? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have gotten the value 218.75 from dividing half the screen (500px) by 16 and then multiplying by 9, which gives 281.25, and then subtracting from 500. However, if you want the thing to be centered remember that there should be 33 divisions on your screen, not 32, as 0 takes up one spot. Moreover, you have split the x-range into 1000 parts, rather than 999.

You need to divide the x range into 999 parts, not 1000, because say if you wanted to get 3 discrete x values in the range 0-1, you divide x by 2 not 3, to get the distance 0.5 separating the x values (0, 0.5, 1). Thus your second x value should not be -3.992 but (-4 + (8/999)) = -3.991991991... and so forth.

Then do something similar for your y values -> take the max range you want, divide it by 999, and use that as your increment to determine the correct pixel height based on your function value.